# MongoDB - match multiple fields same value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I am trying to do something where I can group MongoDB fields for a check.

Given I have following data structure:

```
{
//Some other data fields
created: date,
lastLogin: date,
someSubObject: {
    anotherDate: date,
    evenAnotherDate: date
}
```

On these I want to do a check like this:

```
collection.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        "created": {
            $lt: lastWeekDate
        },
        "someSubObject.anotherDate": {
            $lt: lastWeekDate
        },
        "lastLogin": {
            $lt ...
```

is there a possibility to group the fields and do something like

```
$match: {
    [field1, field2, field3]: {
        $lt: lastWeekDate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) to use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to generate an array of boolean values and then [$allElementsTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/index.html) to apply `AND` condition

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr: {
        $allElementsTrue: {
            $map: {
                input: [ "$field1", "$field2", "$field3" ],
                in: { $lt: [ "$$this", lastWeekDate ] }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

EDIT: if you need that logic as a part of aggregation you can use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) which is an equivalent of `find`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $allElementsTrue: {
                    $map: {
                        input: [ "$field1", "$field2", "$field3" ],
                        in: { $lt: [ "$$this", lastWeekDate ] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: is there a way to do this in an aggregate? Since I need an aggregation for my full query?

Comment: @Tikkes yes you can do that, modified my answer

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @mickl what is "$$this" doing?

Comment: @Seong $map iterates through array elements and $$this repesents currently processed element, similar to `.map($this => $this + 1)` in JavaScript